# trouble with writing array of students using RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, random-access

I had some problems printing out a student store with which I used an `ArrayList`.  I then made a static array to hold these different students and now I'm trying to find out what method I can use to write them.  Here is my code:

```
MainApp
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;



    public class MainApp
    {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
        {
            new MainApp().start();

        }
        public void start()throws Exception 
        {
            StudentStore details = new StudentStore();
            Student a = new Student("Becky O'Brien", "DKIT26", "0876126944", "bexo@hotmail.com");
            Student b = new Student("Fabio Borini", "DKIT28", "0876136944", "fabioborini@gmail.com");
            Student c = new Student("Gaston Ramirez", "DKIT29", "0419834501", "gramirez@webmail.com");
            Student d = new Student("Luis Suarez", "DKIT7", "0868989878", "luissuarez@yahoo.com");
            Student e = new Student("Andy Carroll", "DKIT9", "0853456788", "carroll123@hotmail.com");
            details.add(a);
            details.add(b);
            details.add(c);
            details.add(d);
            details.add(e);
            //details.print();


            RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("ContactDetails.txt","rw");

            Student[] students = {a,b,c,d,e};
            for (int i = 0;i < students.length;i++)
            {
                file.writeByte(students[i]);
            }
            file.close();


         }


     }
```

The line `file.writeByte(students[i]);` is incorrect and I can't find a method to suit this. The error reads the method `writeByte(int)` in the type `RandomAccessFile` is not applicable for the arguments (`Student`).  This is obviously because `writeBytes` method does not take the type student.

Comment: `writeByte` is expecting an int, you passed in an entire `Student` object.

Comment: Correct.  I know that.  What im wondering is what method could be used.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to write out?

Comment: Sounds like you need a `BufferedWriter` and simply implement your own `ToString()` method to customize what a Student print out looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings have a very easy way to convert into bytes. They have a `getBytes()` method that would work well. You can get a string representation of a student by overloading the `toString()` method. So your call would look a lot like

```
file.writeByte(students[i].toString().getBytes( "UTF-8" ));
```

edit:

Forgot getBytes() returns an array of bytes. This should work:

```
byte[] bytes = students[i].toString().getBytes();
for(byte byteWrite : bytes){
    file.writeByte(byteWrite);
}
```

Comment: Have you overrode the toString()?

Comment: How do you override it ? Noob question i know.  But i have never done it before.

Comment: Very simple. Just declare a method called toString() in your student class. See [Here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55)

Comment: @Pendo826 I have also updated my answer. Made a small mistake.

Comment: Where did you get the students from on the first line ?

Comment: And the toString doesn't need to be overrided.  You could have a simple toString like thispublic String toString() 
 {
  return "---------------------------Student--------------------------- " +
    "\nStudent Name:" + studentName + 
    "\nStudent Id:"+ studentId + 
    "\nStudent Telephone Number:"+ studentTelephoneNumber + 
    "\nStudent Email:" + studentEmail;
 }

Answer (score 0):

`RandomAccessFile` is meant to be seek to points in the file and inject values, and I wouldn't recommend it for your purposes. If all you are trying to do is write these lines to a file I would use a `BufferedWriter`. It has everything you need.

BufferedWriter file= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));

and then to write, just put:

file.write(students[i]);

I should warn you that each Student will look like garbage unless you have a custom `toString()` method.

If you just want to write the objects to file in non-readable format, check out [`BufferedOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html)

Comment: I have to use RandomAccessFile :(

Comment: Your professor will only let you use RandomAccessFile? that seems a little silly.

Comment: Teaching you to only use one way to do something seems like a backwards way to teach software development.

Comment: Well we have done normal file i/o.  Im pretty good at this but before yesterday i had never heard of RandomAccessFile.

Comment: Well RAF's have some very good uses, but this isn't their strong suit. I'm glad you got your problem solved though! Good luck with your crazy teacher!

Comment: lol Thanks man. Im sure there are a lot more errors to be found haha.